# cron job with jar file in EC2 linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, cron-task

```
0 16 * * * java -jar /home/ec2-user/movieDataAPI.jar /home/ec2-user/movieData.JSON
```

this is my root crontab list in EC2,
for my understanding, it will run the script every day at 4pm , am I right?
but somehow it didnt seems to work,
I had tried manually

```
java -jar /home/ec2-user/movieDataAPI.jar /home/ec2-user/movieData.JSON
```

run the  code , it is fine. 
the scripting will run 2min to finish the task.
Anyone knows why it cant work?
great thank.

Comment: Jul 19 04:09:01 ip-172-31-42-246 CROND[21054]: (root) CMD (chmod +x /home/ec2-user/movieDataAPI.jar)
Jul 19 04:10:01 ip-172-31-42-246 CROND[21062]: (root) CMD (java -jar /home/ec2-user/movieDataAPI.jar) is this means the cron job get executed

Comment: I think I found out answer, you must chmod to the file that need to be executed and use ec2-user. Dont use root user if you create some file through comands.